# doesn't fire selected index changed event for a drop down list created on run time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, events

Q:

I have the following case :

a button , when clicking on this button , create a drop down list on run time ,and make an event(selected index changed ) for the drop down list..

but what happen is half the previous scenario , i mean creating the drop down list on run time but it doesn't enter the(selected index changed)..

i don't know what is the problem?

Comment: show the code on how you are creating and registering the event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the exact scenario is, but every time you postback, you'll have to create the drop down list and register to the event. Couldn't you hide/show and populate the dropdown box on click of the button? Have a look at the link for a similar issue.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/165499-access-selectedindex-of-dropdownlist-created-at-runtime/

Haven't tried this myself, but this link might help you, if you must add the control dynamically http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2010/04/runtime-add-dynamic-dropdownlist-and.html

Answer (score 1):

did you set `ddl.AutoPostBack = true;` when adding control runtime?